# How can I change the application indicator label after delay?

Tags: indicator, python

How can I change the Application Indicator label after delay

```
self.ind = appindicator.Indicator("new-gmail-indicator", "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/16/ubuntuone-client-error.svg", appindicator.CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS)

self.ind.set_label("SSH")

time.sleep(4)

self.ind.set_label("HSS")
```

The application runs but I only see the `HSS` label when running the application. I never see `SSH`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you've got a single threaded application, and the sleep is blocking it, thus the AppIndicator library doesn't get a chance to update the label.  What you need to do for your timeout is use [GLib's timeout function](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.56/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds) to set up a delay, and change the label in that callback.  The code would probably look something like:

```
def set_label(self):
    self.ind.set_label("SSH")
    GLib.timeout_add(4, self.respond_to_timeout)

def respond_to_timeout(self):
    self.ind.set_label("HSS")
```

Good luck!

Comment: I wanted to do similar thing and I also tried GLib's timeout_add method but it gives me `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. I also tried totally separate thread but it give me `Fatal Python error: ceval: tstate mix-up Aborted (core dumped)`. Though it's an old question, but still hoping to find a solution.

Comment: Try `GLib.timeout_add_seconds` instead.